# Windows 2008 R2 server loses connection to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

One of our many 2008R2 servers constantly loses connection to the domain, meaning that users cannot login to shares etc on the server, and it basically becomes useless.

The event sometimes generated by the server when this happens is 3210 with the error code 0xC0000022.

This does however not always happen.

Running `NETDOM RESETPWD /Server:AD01 /UserD:domainadmin /PasswordD:domainadminpassword` makes it work again until it dies again. Sometimes minutes after, sometimes days after.

We have also tried the usual unjoin/rejoin domain on the server, without success.

This is happening 4-6 times a day at the moment, so it is quite a big issue.

The only services run by the server are file sharing and printing services.

Comment: Mysterious. Is your Sites and Services topology set up correctly? Computer account logons are not chained to the PDCE like user account logon attempts are, so a lack of replication convergence, plus your computer attempting to log on to the wrong site, could equal problems such as this.

Comment: Is this a VM?  You may want to check for time drift.  Check the win32 time service and VMWare tools (if using vmware) for syncing with the host.

Comment: @JamesSantiago - It is actually a VM, and time sync was the first thing we thought of. However, all syncing unless the one within the AD has been disabled with no success. And all the VMware hosts are in sync too.

Comment: @RyanRies - Interesting.. Will try and check up on that on monday, along with checking if there are some SID-duplicates (Since all servers are being made from a template)

Comment: The local machine SID won't cause issues like this. However the computer name may. If the template is being joined to the domain and then cloned, that could definitely cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this problem as well. The stop gap solution I have found is restarting the SERVER service from the Services Control Manager. Obviously it's not a solution, but it keeps me from having to reboot servers every few days.